# Change gridview column header's BackColor

Tags: winforms, gridview

Successfully,placed an image on one of the column headers of my gridview.But its backcolor is all white now, unlike other column headers which are grey, the default back color.How can I change/paint the white to grey.

```
private void GridViewSale_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.RowIndex < 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 1)
      {
          Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(4, 5, 14, 14);              
          e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.DelOn, rec);
          e.Handled = true;
          e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.DeepPink; (//Not working)
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First Set `EnableHeadersVisualStyles="false"` inside your `DataGridView`.Then,

```
    DataGridViewColumn gridviewColumnName = yourGridviewName.Columns[0]; // will set the first column
    gridviewColumnName .HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.DeepPink;
```

Comment: Thank you. But it says 'does not contain a definition for 'Columns'.Where am i missing?

Comment: check now..i have updated the answer..it will work...you need to write - `yourGridviewID.Columns[0]`, that is the id of your `DataGridView`....seems like its `GridViewSale` in your case

Comment: sorry. didnt work.No errors but just ddint change the color.Moreover, setting the EnableHeaderVisualStyles to false, removes separators from the col.header .I tried this in form load as well as cellpainting:      GridViewSale.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = true;    DataGridViewColumn remove = GridViewSale.Columns[1]; remove.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Black;

Comment: Its the same.After the above didnt work: `private void GridViewSale_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e) { if (e.RowIndex < 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 1) { GridViewSale.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = true; Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(3, 5, 15, 15); if(GridViewSale.RowCount>2) e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.DelOn, rec); else e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.DelOff, rec); e.Handled = true; } } `